# Distribution on the linear constraint

Tags: matrices, probability-distributions

How to understand the following Lemma. Any details please, many thanks.

Notations: $\mathcal{N}(a,A)$ denotes Gaussian distribution with mean $a$ and variance $A$. $\overset{\text{d}}{=}$ means statistically equal.

**Lemma**: Let $\boldsymbol{z}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a random vector with i.i.d. $\mathcal{N}(0,v^2)$ entries and let $\boldsymbol{D}\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ be a linear operator with full row rank. Then for any constant vector $\boldsymbol{b}\in \mathbb{R}^m$ the distribution of $\boldsymbol{z}$ conditioned on $\boldsymbol{Dz}=\boldsymbol{b}$ satisfies
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{z}|_{\boldsymbol{Dz}=\boldsymbol{b}}\overset{\text{d}}{=}\boldsymbol{D}^{\top}(\boldsymbol{DD}^{\top})^{-1}\boldsymbol{b}+\text{P}_{\{\boldsymbol{Dz}=\boldsymbol{0}\}}(\tilde{\boldsymbol{z}})
\end{align}
where $\text{P}_{\{\boldsymbol{Dz}=\boldsymbol{0}\}}$ is the orthogonal projection onto the subspace $\{\boldsymbol{Dz}=\boldsymbol{0}\}$ and $\tilde{\boldsymbol{z}}$ is a random vector of i.i.d. $\mathcal{N}(0,v^2)$. Moreover, $\boldsymbol{D}^{\top}(\boldsymbol{DD}^{\top})^{-1}\boldsymbol{b}=\arg\min_{\boldsymbol{z}}\{\|\boldsymbol{z}\|^2|\boldsymbol{Dz}=\boldsymbol{b}\}$.

Also found in the Lemma 10 of "The dynamics of message passing on dense graphs, with applications to compressed sensing".

Comment: The way I see it, it has the classical form of an affine property : a particular solution (the min norm solution here), plus a random variable in the space of the homogeneous solutions. Here it also tells you that this random variable is the orthogonal projection of a Gaussian vector. What other information would you like ?

Comment: @Beleth Thank you.